# "BETWEEN ... AND ..." in GraphQL and Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, sequelize.js

I'm building an API to query a single table in a MySQL database.

I have a field in the table with a date.

I am trying to get all the records between a range of dates (sort of like the mysql "BETWEEN AND" statement.

```
const Person = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Person',
    Description: 'This represents a person',
    fields: () => {
        return {
            firstName: {
                type: GraphQLString,
                resolve(bg) {
                    return bg.name;
                }
            },
            middleName: {
                type: GraphQLString,
                resolve(bg) {
                    return bg.middleName;
                }
            },
            lastName: {
                type: GraphQLString,
                resolve(bg) {
                    return bg.familyName;
                }
            },
            dateOfBirth: {
                type: GraphQLString,
                resolve(bg) {
                    return bg.bornOn;
                }
            },
            sex: {
                type: GraphQLString,
                resolve(bg) {
                    return bg.ses;
                }
            },
            regCode: {
                type: GraphQLString,
                resolve(bg) {
                    return bg.regCode;
                }
            },
            pinCode: {
                type: GraphQLString,
                resolve(bg) {
                    return bg.pinCode;
                }
            },
        }
    }
});

const dateOB = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'date',
    Description: 'This represents a date interval',
    fields: () => {
        return {
            between: {
                type: GraphQLString,
            },
            and: {
                type: GraphQLString,
            }
        }
    }
});

const Query = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'query',
    description: 'This is a root query',
    fields: ()=> {
        return {
            people: {
                type: new GraphQLList(Person, dateOB),
                args: {
                    name: {
                        type: GraphQLString
                    },
                    familyName: {
                        type: GraphQLString
                    },
                    bornOn: {
                        type: GraphQLString
                    }
                },
                resolve(root, args) {
                    return Db.models.bg.findAll({where: args});
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

const Schema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: Query
});
```

I would like to be able to query via a date range on the bornOn argument
sth like "1972-05-05, 2002-01-01" so it only shows records within that range.